# How to login to GitHub when I'm logged out from the GitHub Mobile Authenticator

Tags: authentication, github

I have been using the GitHub Mobile App as my 2FA authenticator. I have somehow been logged out from the GitHub Mobile app. Now I can't sign in to my github account from anywhere, browser or mobile app. When I try to login, they ask me to verify myself via the mobile app, but I'm already logged out from the mobile app. It's kind of a deadlock. I don't have a recovery code either. However, I'm still logged in from my github desktop app. I also have a connection to the account from Vscode too

I tried the customer support portal. They ask me to use a recovery code but I don't have one

Comment: Somewhat related: [Re-enable GitHub two-factor authentication with Authenticator app when switching to a new smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693912/re-enable-github-two-factor-authentication-with-authenticator-app-when-switching)